# Show array values within an array php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, echo

I have a piece of code that loops and displays values for job vacancies:

```
<?php foreach($arrXML as $inner_arr)
foreach($inner_arr as $value) { ?>
        <p>Job Ref: <?php echo $value['jobref']; ?></p>
        <p>Date: <?php echo $value['date']; ?></p>
        <p>Title: <?php echo $value['title']; ?></p>
        <p>Company: <?php echo $value['company']; ?></p>
        <p>Minimum Salary: <?php echo $value['salarymin']; ?></p>
        <p>Maximum Salary: <?php echo $value['salarymax']; ?></p>
        <p>Benefits: <?php echo $value['benefits']; ?></p>
        <p>Salary: <?php echo $value['salary']; ?></p>
        <p>Job Type: <?php echo $value['jobtype']; ?></p>
        <p>Location: <?php echo $value['location']; ?></p>
        <p>Country: <?php echo $value['country']; ?></p>
        <p>Description: <?php echo $value['description']; ?></p>
        <p>Category: <?php echo $value['category']; ?></p>
        <?php } ?>
```

This works great except with some results, the value for Benefits, Salary, Minimum Salary and Maximum Salary maximum return as 'array'.

Is there a way of showing the value if it isn't an array and the array values if it is?

Many thanks

Pete

Comment: You are actually doing the same thing already, including one foreach into another. Why not to just follow the pattern?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: I think the issue here is that OP didn't know how to handle the 'can be value, can be array' variable. Though this has already been covered with `is_array()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (is_array($value['benefits'])) echo "<p>Benefits: ".implode(",",$value['benefits'])."</p>";
else echo "<p>Benefits: ".$value['benefits']."</p>";
```

function `is_array()` explains itself, `implode(c,a)` does convert an array into a string and puts the character `c` between all values of the array. if the array will contain only 1 value, the character `c` will be omitted.

Comment: +1, but please explain at OP why this works and what was the error :)